# How to use left and right arrow keys to navigate in bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Bootstrap 3 menu süstem is defined in html below.
If menu pad is opened, pressing left and right arrow keys is ignored.

How to force left arrow to open previous menu and and right arrow to open next menu pad just like in regular windows menu?
In jquery ui menu bar left and right arrows work in this way. How to make them work in bootstrap navbar also ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <base href="http://localhost:52216/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href="/admin/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/admin/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/admin/Content/Css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/Scripts/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-et.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="skippy" class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content">
        <div class="container"><span class="skiplink-text">Skip to main content</span></div>
    </a>

    <header class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class='dropdown'>
<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button'>Dropdown1
</a>
<ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
<li><a id='menu_OrderCenter' tabindex='-1' >Option1</a></li>
<li><a>Mobiilne tellimus</a></li><li><a >Ostukorv</a></li><li><a id='menu_Artomlii' tabindex='-1' entity='Artomlii' href='Artomlii?_user=admin&_company=1'>Tootepuu</a></li><li><a id='menu_Artomadu' tabindex='-1' entity='Artomadu' href='Artomadu?_user=admin&_company=1'>Tootepuu leht</a></li><li><a id='menu_Artpilt' tabindex='-1' entity='Artpilt' href='Artpilt?_user=admin&_company=1'>Toote pilt</a></li><li><a id='menu_Webconte' tabindex='-1' entity='Webconte' href='Webconte?_user=admin&_company=1'>Sisuhaldus</a></li>
</ul></li>

<li class='dropdown'>
<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button'>Dropdown2
</a>
<ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
<li><a id='menu_Klient' tabindex='-1' entity='Klient' href='Klient?_user=admin&_company=1' title='Ctrl+K'>Klient</a></li><li><a id='menu_ToodeL' tabindex='-1' entity='ToodeL' href='ToodeL?_user=admin&_company=1' title='Ctrl+D'>Artikkel</a></li><li><a id='menu_Konto' tabindex='-1' entity='Konto' href='Konto?_user=admin&_company=1'>Konto</a></li><li><a id='menu_ToodeS' tabindex='-1' entity='ToodeS' href='ToodeS?_user=admin&_company=1'>Summa</a></li><li><a id='menu_ToodeP' tabindex='-1' entity='ToodeP' href='ToodeP?_user=admin&_company=1'>P&#245;hivara</a></li><li><a id='menu_ToodeV' tabindex='-1' entity='ToodeV' href='ToodeV?_user=admin&_company=1'>V&#228;ikevahend</a></li><li><div class='ui-widget-content ui-eeva-separator'></div></li><li><a id='menu_Klliik' tabindex='-1' entity='Klliik' href='Klliik?_user=admin&_company=1'>Kliendi liik</a></li><li><a id='menu_ArtliikL' tabindex='-1' entity='ArtliikL' href='ArtliikL?_user=admin&_company=1'>Artikli liik</a></li><li><a id='menu_Artryhm' tabindex='-1' entity='Artryhm' href='Artryhm?_user=admin&_company=1'>Artikli r&#252;hm</a></li><li><a id='menu_ArtliikP' tabindex='-1' entity='ArtliikP' href='ArtliikP?_user=admin&_company=1'>P&#245;hivara liik</a></li><li><a id='menu_ArtliikV' tabindex='-1' entity='ArtliikV' href='ArtliikV?_user=admin&_company=1'>V&#228;ikevahendi liik</a></li><li><div class='ui-widget-content ui-eeva-separator'></div></li><li><a id='menu_Maksetin' tabindex='-1' entity='Maksetin' href='Maksetin?_user=admin&_company=1'>Maksetingimus</a></li><li><a id='menu_Myygikoo' tabindex='-1' entity='Myygikoo' href='Myygikoo?_user=admin&_company=1'>M&#252;&#252;gikood</a></li><li><a id='menu_Kurss' tabindex='-1' entity='Kurss' href='Kurss?_user=admin&_company=1'>Rahakurss</a></li><li><a id='menu_Pank' tabindex='-1' entity='Pank' href='Pank?_user=admin&_company=1'>Pank</a></li><li><a id='menu_Raha' tabindex='-1' entity='Raha' href='Raha?_user=admin&_company=1'>Raha</a></li>
</ul></li>

<li class='dropdown'>
<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button'>Dropdown3
</a>
<ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
<li><a id='menu_DoklstlG' tabindex='-1' >Arve</a></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstlO' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstlO' href='DoklstlO?_user=admin&_company=1'>Ostuarve</a></li><li><a href='http://localhost:52216/admin/Pay/Index/UnpaidG'>Arve laekumine</a></li><li><a href='http://localhost:52216/admin/Pay/Index/UnpaidO'>Ostuarve tasumine</a></li><li><div class='ui-widget-content ui-eeva-separator'></div></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstdM' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstdM' href='DoklstdM?_user=admin&_company=1' title='Ctrl+M'>Maksekorraldus</a></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstdT' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstdT' href='DoklstdT?_user=admin&_company=1'>Laekumine panka</a></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstdI' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstdI' href='DoklstdI?_user=admin&_company=1'>Kassa sissetulek</a></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstdA' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstdA' href='DoklstdA?_user=admin&_company=1'>Kassa v&#228;ljaminek</a></li><li><div class='ui-widget-content ui-eeva-separator'></div></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstdK' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstdK' href='DoklstdK?_user=admin&_company=1'>Kulu dokument</a></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstdJ' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstdJ' href='DoklstdJ?_user=admin&_company=1'>Muu v&#228;ljastatud</a></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstdU' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstdU' href='DoklstdU?_user=admin&_company=1'>Muu sissetulnud</a></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstlE' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstlE' href='DoklstlE?_user=admin&_company=1'>Leping</a></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstlR' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstlR' href='DoklstlR?_user=admin&_company=1'>Realisatsiooniakt</a></li><li><a id='menu_DoklstdL' tabindex='-1' entity='DoklstdL' href='DoklstdL?_user=admin&_company=1'>Akt</a></li><li><div class='ui-widget-content ui-eeva-separator'></div></li><li><a id='menu_Hinnamtr' tabindex='-1' entity='Hinnamtr' href='Hinnamtr?_user=admin&_company=1'>Hinnamaatriks</a></li><li><a id='menu_Hkpais' tabindex='-1' entity='Hkpais' href='Hkpais?_user=admin&_company=1'>Hinnakujundus</a></li><li><a id='menu_Hkrid' tabindex='-1' entity='Hkrid' href='Hkrid?_user=admin&_company=1'>Hinnakiri</a></li>
</ul></li>



                    <li>
                        <a tabindex='-1' class='logout' href='/admin/Account/LogOff'
                           title='Unusta kasutajanimi ja parool'>
                            Log out
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick for your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
        var $dd = $(this);
        $(document).on('keydown.dd', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 39) {
                $dd.next('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').focus().trigger('click');
            } else if (e.which == 37) {
                $dd.prev('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').focus().trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $(document).off('keydown.dd');
    });
});
```

[**See it in action here**](http://www.bootply.com/crzmG8SxHI)

Comment: Thank you. Great. In sample in dropdown1 pad up and down arrow keys are not working. In other pads thay work. How to fix this ?

Comment: How to highlight (select) first menu item if left or right arrow is pressed ?

Comment: Add ` tabindex="-1"` to the anchors that don't have it to make them navigable with the keys

Comment: In bootstrap 5 it does not work. How to make it in Bootstrap 5 ?

Comment: @Andrus sorry, I haven't used bootstrap or jQuery in 5 years or so.

Comment: I have used your code 6.5 years but after upgrading to Bootstrap 5 it stopped working. I posted this as separate question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70136291/how-to-make-bootstrap-5-navbar-keyboard-accessible

Comment: @Andrus Perfect! I'm no longer well versed in it, and I'm glad to have been able to help for the last 6.5 years :)