# How to make bootstrap 5 navbar keyboard accessible

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How to implement keyboard navigation in bootstrap 5 navbar so that left and right arrow keys open previous/next dropdown menu and letter activates menu item.

Navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown1
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>A</u>ction</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A<u>n</u>other action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>S</u>omething else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown2
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>A</u>ction</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A<u>n</u>other action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>S</u>omething else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown3
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>A</u>ction</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A<u>n</u>other action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>S</u>omething else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried javascript from
[How to use left and right arrow keys to navigate in bootstrap navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983998/how-to-use-left-and-right-arrow-keys-to-navigate-in-bootstrap-navbar) answer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
        var $dd = $(this);
        $(document).on('keydown.dd', function (e) {
          console.log('keydown');
            if (e.which == 39) {
                $dd.next('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').focus().trigger('click');
            } else if (e.which == 37) {
                $dd.prev('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').focus().trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $(document).off('keydown.dd');
    });
});
```

In Bootstrap 5 left and right arrow keys are ignored.
Testcase is in https://www.codeply.com/p/2U6C3qPw2x

If dropdown is opened, how to allow selection from keyboard. Hotkeys are underlined using  element:

[image]

If first dropdown is opened, pressing A should activate first selection , n second selection etc.

Web application is created using ASP.NET 6 MVC . Latest Jquery is also installed.